# C++ functions returning a reference and memory

Tags: c++, memory, optimization

I have in my project a couple of functions that create objects. For example, if you have a function that makes an object like this:

```
int& f()
{
    int *i = new int(5);
    return *i;
}
```

and then when you call that you do

```
int x = f();
```

or something like

```
std::cout << f();
```

what happens to the int that was created in the function? Is the reference handled like a normal variable or am I doing something terribly wrong? And if so, what is the correct way to make objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is terribly wrong, indeed. The moment you forget about your reference is the moment you'll leak a resource. And you're doing just that with `int x = f();`.

Same with the second case, `std::cout << f();` - don't use this at all if you aren't going to `delete` that dynamically allocated `int`.

<sup>`int` is also passed to `std::basic_ostream::operator<<` by value, a copy is made. This doesn't actually matter, no normal code would accept a reference and then call `delete &ref;`.</sup>

Here's a link for you: [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii).

---

I can't know what you want from your contrived example, but consider returning by value, or using smart pointers in case of polymorphism.

Comment: So if I wanted to have a function that initialises an object then returns a reference to that object so you don't have to initialise two objects how would I go about that?

Comment: Do you mean to avoid a copy? [RVO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization) should be able to handle that.

Comment: @user2271513 Shouldn't you use a constructor to initialize an object?

Comment: In this case the constructor is called in the function and then you do some other stuff to the object and then return it. So I have a class with a member function that returns an object of that class based on the members of the class

Comment: @user2271513 Returning such an object by value is perfectly valid common practice. RVO will kick in. Don't optimize prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show that function delegates ownership of the created object with new you have to do it explicitly for example with std::unique_ptr. As you can see your function becomes self documented and you need not look into the body to understand who response for deleting:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> foo() {
   return std::make_unique<int>(5);
}
```